# Define a type which cannot be automatically converted to it's alias

Tags: typescript

Is it possible to define a type in TypeScript that is not automatically inferred as it's alias?

```
type id = string;
type int = number;
```

Then I'd like to get an error if it's not explicitly specified as the declared type:

```
function foo(id: id) {}

var s:string = "123";
foo(s); // error?
```

I would expect `foo("123")` to be an error as well, unless you cast it: `foo("123" as id)`

Comment: That's called a "strong alias".

Comment: There is a way to get this effect in Typescript with something they call "branding".  I'll add an answer if nobody else does so before I get to a non-mobile device (writing code on a phone keyboard is infuriatingly tedious)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main way to get this behavior in TypeScript is a technique called ["branding"](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/tips/nominalTyping.html#using-enums) (also see discussion in [Microsoft/Typescript#4895](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4895)).  The idea is that you augment the base type with a "brand" that has no runtime effects, but which causes the type system to distinguish it from the base type.

For your case, we could do something like this:

```
type id = string & { __brand: 'id' };
type int = number & { __brand: 'int' };

function foo(id: id) {}

var s:string = "123";
foo(s); // error
foo("123"); // error
foo("123" as id) //okay
```

As you can see, it behaves more or less exactly as you want.  Notice that it still considers the branded type to be compatible with the base type, so you can  do this:

```
const i: int = 5 as int;
const j: number = i; // that's okay, an int is a number
```

The main downside of this technique is that you're basically lying to the type system: there is no `__brand` property on a `string` or `number`.  But if branding is [good enough for the compiler itself](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4895#issuecomment-142428454), it's probably good enough for us.

There are other ways you can do branding/tagging, but that should work for you.  Good luck!

Comment: Thank you @jcalz, this is exactly what I was looking for! After you left a comment telling me about branding, I found the Typescript FAQ on the [GitHub wiki](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ) which contained a section about nominal type aliases, among other gems.. Thanks again!

Comment: Is this also how you'd handle, say, two interfaces with the same property names and types that shouldn't be mutually-assignable, or would you use a `kind` property or similar?

Comment: If I'm writing the runtime code as well as the types then I'd use a real discriminating property like `kind`.  If I'm just writing types for an existing js library that I can't modify, then I'd probably use branding.  (Of course `kind` and `__brand` are just names and you can use `foo` for each of them; the only difference between branding and regular discriminated unions is that the former is just a convenient fiction at design time)

Answer (score 1):

Think that is not possible, since TS is using structural and not nominal typing. You can find more information here:

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html

Guess if you need this feature, you have to switch to flow-type. They got this: https://flow.org/en/docs/types/opaque-types/

EDIT: Guess this is what the TS team has planned: [Microsoft/TypeScript#5228](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5228)

Comment: Thank you for the interesting read, I've kind of written off flow for being very similar to TypeScript. I'll have to look further what other things it has.